# Задача на Codewars

Tags: javascript

https://www.codewars.com/kata/sum-of-differences-in-array/train/javascript

мой способ решения:

```
function sumOfDifferences(arr) {
  let arrR = arr.reverse();
  let num = 0;
  for(let i = 0; i < arrR.length; i++) {
    if(i == arr.length-1){break}
    num = num +(arrR[i]-arrR[i+1])
  }
  return num;
}
```

28 правильно, 80 не правильно, в чем собственно проблема?

---

> https://www.codewars.com/kata/sum-of-differences-in-array/train/javascript
>
> Your task is to sum the differences between consecutive pairs in the array in descending order.
>
> For example: `sumOfDifferences([1, 2, 10]` Returns `9`
>
> Descending order: `[10, 2, 1]`
>
> Sum: `(10 - 2) + (2 - 1) = 8 + 1 = 9`
>
> If the array is empty or the array has only one element the result should be `0`.
>
> ---
>
> Ваша задача состоит в том, чтобы суммировать разницу между последовательными парами в массиве в порядке убывания.
>
> например: `sumOfDifferences([1, 2, 10]` вернёт `9`
>
> В порядке убывания: `[10, 2, 1]`
>
> Сум: `(10 - 2) + (2 - 1) = 8 + 1 = 9`
>
> Если массив пуст или массив имеет только один элемент, результат должен быть
>   `0`.

Comment: а что за задача-то?

Comment: задача по ссылке

Comment: 28 правильно, 80 не правильно© эт чо такое

Comment: результат моего решения

Comment: перенеси описание непосредственно в вопрос

Answer (score 1):

`arr.reverse();` недостаточно - ведь массив не всегда будет сортирован по возрастанию, так что нужно самому отсортировать

Если маленько подумать, то цикл не нужен - всё сократится, и достаточно вот чего:

```
    function sumOfDifferences(arr) {
      if (arr.length<2)
        return 0;
      arrS = arr.sort(function(a,b){return a-b;});
      return arrS[arrS.length - 1] - arrS[0];
    }
```

Или вообще без сортировки:

```
  return Math.max.apply(null, arr) - Math.min.apply(null, arr);
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, одна поправка условие для сортировки не (a-b), а (b-a)

Comment: @Flatron Samatron Я использовал разницу `последний минус первый`, поэтому такая сортировка

Comment: Если маленько подумать© по мне - это частный случай (из математики, программирования и т.д.). расскажите пожалуйста, как нужно подумать, чтобы прийти к выводу, что промежуточные элементы взаимноисключающие ?

Comment: @qwabra  `[10, 7, 5, 1] =>  (10 - 7) + (7 - 5) + (5 - 1) =  3  + 2 + 4 = 9 = 10 - 1`  все средние значения встречаются по два раза с **+** и с **-**, и при раскрытии скобок взаимно уничтожаются,остаются лишь крайние

Comment: хмм, спасибо. `[10, 7, 5, 1] => (10 - 7) + (7 - 5) + (5 - 1) = 10 + (- 7 + 7) + ( - 5 + 5) + - 1` вот смотрю теперь и думаю - ну очевидно же : )

Answer (score 0):

> Q: в чем собственно проблема?
>
> A: в порядке убывания

решение

```
let sumOfDifferences = arr => arr.length < 2
    ? 0
    : arr
        .sort((a, b) => b - a)
        .map((v, i, a) => (void 0 === a[i + 1]) ? 0 : v - a[i + 1])
        .reduce((res, val, i, arr) => res + val, 0)
```

Comment: а я не знал что так писать можно с новой строки..  __sort__ , __map__ __reduce__

Comment: дык. классический чэйнинг жеж

Comment: я вот жду. когда можно будет вот так писать https://github.com/tc39/proposal-pipeline-operator

Comment: спасибо за это я не знал про <<чэйнинг>> .И насчет ссылки это вообще извращенство не надо так писать.И вопрос тут имя функции у тебя это __arr__ правильно (который присваиваетсья переменной)??

Comment: `sumOfDifferences` - анонимная стрелочная функция присвоенная переменной `arr` - входной параметра затем сразу возвращается результат, без тела функции - тернарный оператор, в условии else, в конце - чейнинг массива.

Comment: благодарью .. :)

Comment: не надо так писать© ну да, ну да. давайте писать с права на лево и ещё кучу скобочек ставить. приведённая мной ссылка - это спека js

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84473/discussion-between---and-qwabra).

Answer (score -1):

Очень простой код. Если длина массива меньше 2 — тоже работает.

```js
function res (input) {
  let result = 0

  input.slice(1).forEach((item, i) => 
    result += input[i] - item
  )
  
  return Math.abs(result)
}

console.log(res([1, 2, 10]))
console.log(res([5]))
```